# How to make a label do marquee left and marquee right?

Tags: c#, text, checkbox, label, marquee

I am trying to find the EASIEST way possible of making a labels text scroll via by typing the text into a textbox. I can't seem to find a good honest tutorial for both right and left can someone please give me an example of what to do?

I don't care if it is smooth or not

Comment: That's because it is very difficult to make the scrolling look smooth.  But more so because users absolutely *hate* stuff that moves that's not in their field of vision.  Lions live there, if you've never ran for your life then you can't really appreciate the notion of being dinner.  You might as well make an animated GIF to irk the hell out of your users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a label scroll a word back and forth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244800/how-to-make-a-label-scroll-a-word-back-and-forth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a timer, you could prepend spaces to the text one-by-one up to a point.  Then remove the spaces one-by-one until they are all gone.  That will make the text go right and left....and possibly irritate your users.