# How to make a label scroll a word back and forth?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, marquee

I came up with the idea of making a label scroll a word to one side and then change the word and scroll back to the other like so

```
   "ping           "
   " ping          "
   "  ping         "
   "   ping        "
   "    ping       "
   "     ping      "
   "      ping     "
   "       ping    "
   "        ping   "
   "         ping  "
   "          ping "
   "           ping"
   "           pong"
   "          pong "
   "         pong  "
   "        pong   "
   "       pong    "
   "      pong     "
   "     pong      "
   "    pong       "
   "   pong        "
   "  pong         "
   " pong          "
   "pong           "
```

I want it to do ^^ only in a constant loop but I don't know how I would even get started doing that I would REALLY appreciate it if someone could help me with this. The max length of the text has to be 15 characters.

I don't care if it is smooth scrolling.

I want it to be a Winforms application and use .Net framework 4.0.

Comment: Is this a winforms project or a console project?

Comment: In Windows Form Application you can do it using a Timer component, in WPF /SilverLight Application you can use an Animation, in Web Applications you can use javascript. Please describe which target are you looking the answer for (and framework version too).

Comment: I want to use a timer and that streams that text so it looks like it bounces off of each side and framework 4.0

Comment: [Here's](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Components/MarqueeLabelDemo.htm) a primitive example that should be fairly easy to modify for your needs.

Comment: Was it necessary to ask this question twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a for-loop that runs from 0 to 11 (15 - length of "ping"). With `new String(' ', i)` you can create a string that is `i` spaces long. Then set the Text of your label to this space string concatenated with the word "ping".

Now you can make another loop, running from 11 down to 0 doing the same but with the word "pong".

If you enclose both loops in an endless loop (`while (true) { ... }`) this will run indefinitely.

You also might want to add a pause each time after you set the label text with `Thread.Sleep(200)`. Where you specify the time is in milliseconds.

---

EDIT (since it is not homework):

Go to the events tab in the properties window and add a `Shown` event handler

```
private void frmMarquee_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            label1.Text = new String(' ', i) + "ping";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        for (int i = 11; i >= 0; i--) {
            label1.Text = new String(' ', i) + "pong";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

Note, this solution is not perfect, as the form will not close properly. You will have to abort the program. A solution using a timer will work smoother and the form will behave as expected when closing, however this is a straightforward and simple solution.

Comment: TYVM! i have been trying to figure this out forever now if i can just figure out how to write what you said :/ lol

Comment: It looks like homework to me. Do you really want us to do all your homework? see [for loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx), [concatenate strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx), [while loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: It's not homework I am trying to make a program for my benefit

Comment: I have seen 4 or five questions posted very recently asking basically the same question. This made me think its homework.

Comment: None seem to have been selected as an answer on the other questions either.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Why are you doing a `DoEvents` after a `Thread.Sleep`? Besides `DoEvents` are generally evil, if you sleep the thread then you've opened a window for other threads to execute.

Comment: The form does not update any more without the `DoEvents`. Alternatively you could do a `this.Refresh();`. However, as I stated in my answer, a solution with a timer would not have this problem.

Comment: i hate to sound like a total novice lol but i am not very good with timers i never really use them i usually do thread.sleep how would i implement this into a timer? if i knew i probably wouldnt need help with timer again lol

Comment: See [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.71).aspx) on MSDN. The answer of @TheSavage places a timer control on the form and adapts the timer parameters in the properties window. Then he adds a Tick event handler.

Comment: and also Olivier you are the most helpful person I have come across on this site so far lol thanks for that and this.

Comment: @Sdry: It is just an exercise. I would do it as a console app, then this would not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do, it seemed to work just fine when I tested it out, I created a windows form with a timer and label on it. Make sure to call timer.Start() when you open the form and it will start bouncing around the screen. If you change iUBound to a larger value it will move more spaces across the screen.

```
    string _sPing = "ping";
    string _sPong = "pong";
    bool bGoingUp = true;
    int iUBound = 15;
    int iCnt = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (bGoingUp)
        {
            label1.Text = " " + label1.Text;
            iCnt++;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = label1.Text.Substring(1,label1.Text.Length - 1);
            iCnt--;
        }

        if (iCnt == iUBound)
        {
            bGoingUp = false;
            label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace(_sPing, _sPong);
        }
        else if (iCnt == 1)
        {
            bGoingUp = true;
            label1.Text = label1.Text.Replace(_sPong, _sPing);
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep the label contents the same and just move the label, feels like it should be less CPU load and the scrolling will be smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this example](http://www.codersource.net/microsoft-net/c-winforms/scrolling-text-on-a-form-using-label-control.aspx). Pretty close to what you want. The two key elements are (1)using StringBuilder functions to append characters and (2) an asynchronous delegate to put the animation in a different thread.

The idea of the `StringBuilder` is great because it should be more efficient that dealing with `String`. And I like `Asynchronous delegate` because it sounds way more impressive than `Timer`

Comment: Doing multithreaded applications can get tricky when dealing with UI. Delegates are great, but for the complexity Ian is talking about, it may be a bit of overkill