# Make a TextView scroll its Content in a "bouncing" sort of fashion

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Right now i am implementing a custom Renderer for my Xamarin.Forms Label with which i can make use of the marquee scrolling features of the TextView.

What i want to do now is change the scrolling mode of the text from just going to the left endlessly to "bouncing" from side to side. (Kind of like this question i found regarding this subject: [How to make a label scroll a word back and forth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244800/how-to-make-a-label-scroll-a-word-back-and-forth)) I have not found any resources online that talk about this. I would be very happy if you could give me a general idea of where to look or what to do.

Thank you for your time

Here is my marquee Custom-Renderer:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        MarqueeLabel marqLabel = (MarqueeLabel)this.Element;
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (marqLabel.shouldScroll)
        {
            Control.SetSingleLine(true);
            Control.SetHorizontallyScrolling(true);
            Control.Selected = true;
            Control.Ellipsize = Android.Text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.Marquee;
            Control.SetMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you have currently in your custom renderer?

Comment: Right now, all im doing is typical marquee scrolling, ill edit it into the question.

Comment: Could you not just use the animation classes in Xamarin.Forms?  rather than go down to the platform level?

Comment: I have never worked with Animations in XF before so i dont really know how to answer that question...

Answer (score 0):

If you can do the animations on the `Xamarin.Forms` level then you can save yourself quite a bit of work rather than implementing on each platform-specific level.

Try the following example that demonstrates some bouncing of a `Label` to and from the edges of the screen, as it may give you some ideas?  Note it doesn't do it continuously in the example below.

```
StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()            
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
};

Label objLabel = new Label();
objLabel.Text="Hello";
objLabel.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel);


Button objButton1 = new Button()
{
    Text = "Animate"
};

objButton1.Clicked += (async (o2, e2) =>
{
    double dblWidth = objStackLayout.Width - objLabel.Width;
    //
    await objLabel.TranslateTo(dblWidth, 0,1000, Easing.BounceIn);
    await objLabel.TranslateTo(0,0,1000, Easing.BounceIn);
});

objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton1);
```

Comment: Im so sorry for not being clear in my question, what i am trying to do is scroll the Text, not the View.

Comment: On Android, you have the `TranslateAnimation` class.  To get the bounce you will need to set an `Interpolator`.  Once all configured you can apply it to your a `Android` `TextView` like objTextView.startAnimation(objTranslateAnimation).

Comment: Im still not sure if i was clear at all.. sorry about that. What i am trying to do is scroll the Text inside my TextView, the position of the TextView should not change. And i can have it scroll marquee (like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwJqaGHoflE&feature=youtu.be&t=307) but i want the behaviour to change.

Comment: @StarterPack Sounds like you want to do all the paint drawing of text yourself perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the good way to do that but I am sure this will solve your problem.

```
 StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        };

        Label lblMarquee = new Label();
        lblMarquee.Text = "This is marquee animation!!!";
        lblMarquee.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(lblMarquee);


        Button btnAnimate = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Stare Marquee Animation"
        };

        btnAnimate.Clicked += (async (o2, e2) =>
        {
            double dblWidth = objStackLayout.Width + lblMarquee.Width;
            // Infinite loop
            while (true)
            {
                lblMarquee.IsVisible = false;
                await lblMarquee.TranslateTo(dblWidth / 2, 0, 500, Easing.SinIn);
                lblMarquee.IsVisible = true;
                await lblMarquee.TranslateTo(-(dblWidth / 2), 0, 10000, Easing.SinIn);

            }
        });

        objStackLayout.Children.Add(btnAnimate);
        Content = objStackLayout;
    }
```

NOTE: You can remove the infinite loop and try the same with **TPL** that will be good way to handle never ending task instead of using infinite loop.